# Multiple sitemap in drupal using xmlsitemap module

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, seo, xml-sitemap

I want to create Multiple sitemap in drupal using xmlsitemap module

1. Static pages like About-us/Contact us etc
2. Content pages pages from specific content type.

A index file which will contain entry for both XML
Its not a multilingual or multidomain site.

Thanks

Comment: It does offer creating different links but combines everything in one. Either you can modify the module or you can use its API to alter this behaviour

Comment: Can't modify module its against law :-).Can you be specific about API.

Comment: >> Can't modify module its against law << This is not true, Drupal and all modules/themes or any piece of code hosted under drupal.org IS and MUST be GPL-2 or later compliant thus is open-source, so you can modify or redistribute the code. For more information about this and 3rd party software refer to the official page https://www.drupal.org/about/licensing